# Postgresql/Postgis bug in ST_ApproximateMedialAxis?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I get what seems like a bug in `Postgresql/Postgis`. This is a completely reproducible example that demonstrates the problem:

```
#create a new srid for local area (formula for proj4text is taken from Quantum GIS)
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text) VALUES (998997, 'EPSG', 998997, '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=44.55 +k=1 +x_0=2250000 +y_0=-5714743.504 +ellps=krass +towgs84=24,-123,-94,0.02,-0.25,-0.13,1.1 +units=m +no_defs ');

#create a new table for storing geometry data:
CREATE TABLE layer(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  geom geometry,
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geom_layer CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geom_layer CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 998997)
);

#add one polygon to the table:
INSERT INTO layer (geom) VALUES (ST_Force2D(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((4832654.676302 7570323.2813639, 4810946.560269 7597840.6115465, 4836629.4017728 7629944.1634263, 4886772.0923279 7629944.1634263, 4902059.4979849 7591725.6492837, 4864452.4800686 7553507.1351411, 4832654.676302 7570323.2813639),(4845190.3489408 7589891.1606049, 4855585.7847875 7610376.2841853, 4876988.1527074 7604567.0700356, 4874847.9159154 7588362.4200392, 4858031.7696927 7575520.9992872, 4845190.3489408 7589891.1606049))', 3857),998997)));

#check that this polygon is valid!
SELECT ST_IsValid(ST_Force2D(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((4832654.676302 7570323.2813639, 4810946.560269 7597840.6115465, 4836629.4017728 7629944.1634263, 4886772.0923279 7629944.1634263, 4902059.4979849 7591725.6492837, 4864452.4800686 7553507.1351411, 4832654.676302 7570323.2813639),(4845190.3489408 7589891.1606049, 4855585.7847875 7610376.2841853, 4876988.1527074 7604567.0700356, 4874847.9159154 7588362.4200392, 4858031.7696927 7575520.9992872, 4845190.3489408 7589891.1606049))', 3857),998997))) AS is_valid;
#^^^ it returns t. so, the geometry is 100% ok.

#check how it looks like in geojson format:
SELECT  ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 3857))::json from layer
#^^^ Again it's ok and returns some nice geojson data

#Final step. Check ST_ApproximateMedialAxis function
SELECT ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(ST_Transform(geom, 3857)) from layer;
```

The final query returns an error message:

> ERROR:  Polygon is invalid : exterior ring and interior ring 0 have the same orientation : POLYGON((5189023446929109/1073741824 2032143182100511/268435456,5165714534831303/1073741824 31867653268373/4194304,1298322818976529/268435456 8192590163056015/1073741824,26
>
> ********** Error **********

So, all ingredients seem to be ok - formula for srid is taken from some standard widely used tool, data is inserted into the table without problems, the data is validated by ST_IsValid, geojson representation of data is also ok, but one library function still does not like something.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this nice [thread](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2008-November/021763.html) and came to the solution. I just have to use [ST_ForceRHR](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForceRHR.html) Postgis function which

> forces the orientation of the vertices in a polygon to follow the Right-Hand-Rule

So the right way to insert the data was:

```
INSERT INTO layer (geom) VALUES (ST_Force2D(ST_Transform(ST_ForceRHR(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((4832654.676302 7570323.2813639, 4810946.560269 7597840.6115465, 4836629.4017728 7629944.1634263, 4886772.0923279 7629944.1634263, 4902059.4979849 7591725.6492837, 4864452.4800686 7553507.1351411, 4832654.676302 7570323.2813639),(4845190.3489408 7589891.1606049, 4855585.7847875 7610376.2841853, 4876988.1527074 7604567.0700356, 4874847.9159154 7588362.4200392, 4858031.7696927 7575520.9992872, 4845190.3489408 7589891.1606049))', 3857)),998997)));
```